# How to create a button on a new widget using grid() method in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk  


 class Main:
        def __init__(self, parent):
            self.parent = parent
            self.button = tk.Button(text="Build", command=self.new_window)
            self.button.grid(row=1, column=0)

        def new_window(self):
            self.window = tk.Tk()
            self.app = Graph(self.window)
            self.window.mainloop()


  class Graph:
      def __init__(self, parent):
          self.parent = parent
          self.new_button = tk.Button(text="text")
          self.new_button.grid(in_=self.parent)
 def main():
      root = tk.Tk()
      app = Main(root)
      root.mainloop()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Here's my code and I'm trying to create a button on a new widget using grid() + in_, but there is a problem - button dont creates on a new widget instead of this it creates on  the main one.

Comment: It appears you have some indentation errors other than that thanks a lot for updating to an MCVE. I could fix them as I know that wasn't the problem but I think you should do it yourself for your own good.

Comment: Just note that you can copy/paste your code, then select the entirety of the code lines and press Ctrl+K or use `{}` looking button above to make your code snippet _appear_ as code.

Comment: Also note that by default an indentation level = 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tkinter` widgets are by default assigned to root window, `Tk` unless passed a parent widget as the first positional argument, which is omitted in:

```
self.new_button = tk.Button(text="Destroy", command=self.destroy)
```

You should replace it with:

```
self.new_button = tk.Button(parent, text="Destroy", command=self.destroy)
```